# Calculate large numbers into 100% percent bar width

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a progress bar using:
https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/progress

And I'm having values that are **larger** than 100.
Every response that I'm getting back can return me a different list of numbers and most of the time they will be larger than 100.

Sample of one of my responses is:

> value:  51460 value:  35947 value:  21452 value:  12750 value:  7534
> value:  6969 value:  5877 value:  5829 value:  5288 value:  75386

I would like to know how can I calculate big numbers in a way that I can set them as the width of the progress component and it will be inside the 100% width limit?

Thank you,

Comment: You need to divide these numbers by some maximum value e.g. 75,386 / 100,000 will get you a value between 0 and 1 (0.75386 in this example). Multiplying that by 100 will get you a percentage in the range 0 - 100 (75.386%).

Comment: Figure out your maximum value. Say 40,000. Then take your values and divide each one by that maximum. E.g. 12750/4000 = .31875. Multiple that by 100 to get 31.875% and repeat for each one

Comment: are you looking for the % of all the numbers in the response? i.e for values above would be `[22,16,9,6,3,3,3,3,2,33]` to fit in a single bar?

Answer (score 0):

You must know the maximum value that you will receive.

With that you can use `percentage = (currentValue / maxValue) * 100` and then use that value as the 0-100 value.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing percentages of any number you should know its maximum

Let's say as an example you're transferring files

You have 50 000 files in total

In this case you have

```
max = 50000;
current = getFilesTransferred(); //returns current number of files transferred
percentage = (current / max) * 100; //calculate percentage of transferred files
console.log("Files transferred : %" + percentage); // this will print as an example "Files Transferred : %20" for current = 10 000
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution if you are looking for the % of all the numbers in the response, distributed between 100%.

```css
.el-row {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/index.css">
<div id="app">
  <el-row>
    <el-col :span="24">
      <h1>Percentage of all values distributed between 100%</h1>
    </el-col>
  </el-row>
  <el-row v-for="(value, index) in values" :key="index">
    <el-col :span="4">
      <div>
        {{ value }} = {{ result[index] }}%
      </div>
    </el-col>
    <el-col :span="20">
      <div>
        <el-progress :text-inside="true" :stroke-width="20" :percentage="result[index]"></el-progress>
      </div>
    </el-col>
  </el-row>
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/element-ui/lib/index.js"></script>
<script>
  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: function() {
      return {
        values: [51460, 35947, 21452, 12750, 7534, 6969, 5877, 5829, 5288, 75386]
      }
    },
    computed: {
      result() {
        return this.percentRound(this.values)
      }
    },
    methods: {
      percentRound(ipt, precision) {
        if (!precision) {
          precision = 0
        }
        if (!Array.isArray(ipt)) {
          throw new TypeError('percentRound input should be an Array')
        }
        const iptPercents = ipt.slice()
        const length = ipt.length
        const out = new Array(length)

        let total = 0
        for (let i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
          if (typeof iptPercents[i] === 'string') {
            iptPercents[i] = Number.parseFloat(iptPercents[i])
          }
          total += iptPercents[i] * 1
        }
        if (isNaN(total)) {
          throw new TypeError('percentRound invalid input')
        }

        if (total === 0) {
          out.fill(0)
        } else {
          const powPrecision = Math.pow(10, precision)
          const pow100 = 100 * powPrecision
          let check100 = 0
          for (let i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            iptPercents[i] = 100 * iptPercents[i] / total
            check100 += out[i] = Math.round(iptPercents[i] * powPrecision)
          }

          if (check100 !== pow100) {
            const totalDiff = (check100 - pow100)
            const roundGrain = 1
            let grainCount = Math.abs(totalDiff)
            const diffs = new Array(length)

            for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
              diffs[i] = Math.abs(out[i] - iptPercents[i] * powPrecision)
            }

            while (grainCount > 0) {
              let idx = 0
              let maxDiff = diffs[0]
              for (let i = 1; i < length; i++) {
                if (maxDiff < diffs[i]) {
                  idx = i
                  maxDiff = diffs[i]
                }
              }
              if (check100 > pow100) {
                out[idx] -= roundGrain
              } else {
                out[idx] += roundGrain
              }
              diffs[idx] -= roundGrain
              grainCount--
            }
          }
          if (powPrecision > 1) {
            for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
              out[i] = out[i] / powPrecision
            }
          }
        }

        return out
      }
    }
  })
</script>

</html>
```